# Добавить MySQL в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

Для работы с БД MySQL пытаюсь импортировать **mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar** в проект:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
```

на что после запуска проекта получаю ответ:

```
Error:(2, 12) java: package java.sql is not visible
  (package java.sql is declared in module java.sql, but module javaFXfirst does not read it)
```

в файле проекта **module-info.java** нужно было добавить строку  `requires java.sql;` и так заработало

Comment: Скинь, пожалуйста, часть кода, где ты это используешь

Comment: перепроверь правильность добавление jar в проект: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project

Comment: Если ты через Maven делаешь - то https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.14

Comment: Если я вам помог, можете пометить правильный ответ галочкой

Comment: Что у вас в файлах module.info?

Comment: Maxim ,module untitledhh {
    requires javafx.fxml;
requires javafx.controls;
requires mysql.connector.java;
opens sample;
}

Comment: Antonio112009, перешел по вашей ссылке, скачал и сделал как в инструкции, результат тот же

Comment: Maxim, в module.info нужно было дописать    requires java.sql; и заработало

Answer (score 1):

Класс java.sql.Connection представляет в JDBC сеанс работы с базой данных. Он предоставляет приложению объекты Statement (и его подклассы) для этого сеанса. Он также управляет транзакциями для этих команд. По умолчанию каждая команда выполняется в отдельной транзакции. Объект Connection позволяет отключить функцию Autocommit автоматического завершения транзакции. В этом случае требуется явно завершить транзакцию, иначе результаты выполнения всех команд будут потеряны.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.14</version>
</dependency>
```

Помести это в dependencies в файл pom.xml.

Для работы с MySql в Java необходимо установить официальный драйвер MySQL Connector/J.
Так же если ты используешь `Maven`, то посмотри в файле pom.xml (есть ли artifact (mysql connector java)
[Maven artifact](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.14) там посмотри ниже код, скопируй и вставь в pom.xml его, если у тебя gradle, то и для gradle там тоже есть код в другой вкладке на этой же странице. Это последняя версия коннектора, про них почитай тоже и поймешь. Но нужна больше информации и больше кода, чтобы мы могли понять, что у тебя случилось. А вообще ознакомься с [JDBC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity).